# Is there a more efficient way of returning a boolean from a method with multiple objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, boolean

Pardon my phrasing of the question, I'm still fairly new to Java so I wasn't sure how to word it. Basically, I have created an inventory and added 2 different methods:

```
public class Inventory 
{   
    String name;
    Items myItems = new Items();
    boolean addFoodItem;
    boolean addDrinkItem;
    boolean addToyItem;
    boolean addCampingItem;

    boolean removeFoodItem;
    boolean removeDrinkItem;
    boolean removeToyItem;
    boolean removeCampingItem;

    
    ArrayList<Objects> inventory = new ArrayList<Objects>();
    Objects myObjects = new Objects(name);
    
    public boolean AddToInventory (boolean addFoodItem, boolean addDrinkItem, boolean addToyItem, boolean addCampingItem)
    {
        if (addFoodItem)
        {
            inventory.add(myItems.foodItem);
            System.out.println("You have added 1 " + myItems.FoodItem.name + " to your 
            inventory.");
        }

        if (addDrinkItem)
        {
            inventory.add(myItems.drinkItem);
            System.out.println("You have added 1 " + myItems.DrinkItem.name + " to your 
            inventory.");
        }

        if (addToyItem)
        {
            inventory.add(myItems.toyItem);
            System.out.println("You have added 1 " + myItems.ToyItem.name + " to your 
            inventory.");
        }

        if (addCampingItem)
        {
            inventory.add(myItems.campingItem);
            System.out.println("You have added 1 " + myItems.CampingItem.name + " to your 
            inventory.");
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean RemoveFromInventory(boolean removeFoodItem, boolean removeDrinkItem, boolean 
                                       removeToyItem, boolean removeCampingItem)
    {           
        if (removeFoodItem)
        {
            inventory.remove(myItems.foodItem);
            System.out.println("You have used 1 " + myItems.foodItem.name + " from your 
                                inventory.");
        }

        if (removeDrinkItem)
        {
            inventory.remove(myItems.drinkItem);
            System.out.println("You have used 1 " + myItems.drinkItem.name + " from your 
                                inventory.");
        }

        if (removeToyItem)
        {
            inventory.remove(myItems.toyItem);
            System.out.println("You have used 1 " + myItems.toyItem.name + " from your 
                                inventory.");
        }

        if (removeCampingItem)
        {
            inventory.remove(myItems.campingItem);
            System.out.println("You have used 1 " + myItems.campingItem.name + " from your 
                                inventory.");
        }

        return true;
    }       
    
    public void GetInventory()
    {
        for (Objects items : inventory)
        {
            System.out.println(items.name);
        }    
    }
```

There will be more objects that will be added to this script which is why I am looking to see if there is a potentially more efficient way of doing this. The ***Items.java*** class simply creates the objects and the ***Objects.java*** class only returns the name of the object so it can be printed. All of this code works, but as I add more items, I need to keep switching the booleans to true and false in other classes just to have the AddToInventory and RemoveFromInventory methods to run.

So my question is, what is a more efficient way of checking if I need to add to and/or remove multiple objects from an inventory (ArrayList). I have considered using a method for each individual check (for add to or subtracting from inventory), but ruled it out as it is not much different from the methods I have above.
Thanks everyone!

My thoughts behind this are if I call this method from another class and switch the boolean to true, these methods execute the code within the if statement and will either add or remove from the "inventory" ArrayList. The inefficiency that I see is when calling this method from another class, I have to include all the booleans in the arguments for example:

```
if (//add check here)
{
    Inventory.AddToInventory (boolean addFoodItem = true, boolean 
    addDrinkItem = false, boolean addToyItem = false, boolean addCampingItem 
    = false)
}
```

With more items being added, this is quite the chunk of text. This is what I'd like to clean up if possible.

Comment: If only `return true;` is returned then there is no point doing it.  Also fail to see what is in-efficient.

Comment: Try having a single `abstract class Item`, and have subclasses `CampingItem`, `ToyItem`, etc.  This way, `addToInventiory` simply adds to the list - no more code changes just because you have added a new type of item.

Comment: Is this a form with radio buttons, or with checkboxes? You can probably do something like `foreach option O in List L { if (checked/selected) { <add item to inventory> } }`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do an Enum representing every item, and after the operation is done (addition/removal), return that Enum. This way, you will know on which kind of item was performed the operation.

Also, in your current code, instead of multiple ifs, it would look better to have a switch case.

Answer (score 0):

I used @racraman suggestion and created a super class with subclasses for all items so there isn't this big long argument of item booleans in a method. Since then I have added 10 new objects so that list would have been pretty long and ugly to repeat everytime!